# Consultas mysql INNER JOIN Duda

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo 3 tablas 2 de ellas mostraran el contenido principal de la web mi consulta no me esta dando los resultados esperados ya que recien empese a usar inner join por motivos de performance en las consultas y facilitar mas el codigo por supuesto, en fin definicion de las 3 tablas: tabla **"AMIGOS"** contiene los amigos entre si,tabla **"CONTENIDO"**  contiene el post con foto,nombre,apellido etc.. y la otra es tabla es **"COPIAS"**  practicamente es una copia de los post osea de la tabla **"CONTENIDO"** necesito mostrar el contenido de esas 2 tablas ordenada por fecha pero con algunas condiciones tales como que me muestre los post de solo mis amigos y las copias que hayga de esos post de la tabla COPIAS se que suena raro lo de las copias pero son ideas mias jeje aqui les comparto mi codigo y imagen de las tablas relacionadas.

NOTA: lo que yo quiero lograr ya lo he logrado pero no con inner join si no con consultas separadas pero quiero que mi codigo sea eficiente no se si me doy a entender, este es mi codigo .

[image: este es el diseno de mis tablas]

como veran las tablas estan relacionadas incluyendo tambien la principal que es la de registro y pueden ver que **contenido** y **copia** estan relacionadas por el id de la tabla contenido con el id_post de la tabla copias, osea cada ves que el usuario hace una copia de su post ese id del post se guarda el la tabla copias como **id_post**

```
 <?php
        /*aqui voy a sacar el id de las personas que son mis amigos, nota:
     el campo *DE* contiene mi id de session y el campo *PARA* contiene los id
    de los usuarios que yo le envie la solicitud ojala entiendan */
     $get_my_freinds_id=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM amigos 
          WHERE  de='{$_SESSION["id"]}' ");
          $row=mysqli_fetch_array( $get_my_freinds_id);
           $myselect =mysqli_query($conexion," SELECT * FROM
         contenido INNER JOIN copias 
         ON contenido.id = copias.post_id 
         WHERE contenido.id_user='{$row["para"]}' OR 
          copias.id_user='{$row["para"]}'");

             while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($myselect)){

             ?>
  <!-- aqui en un div quiero mostrar la informacion de las dos tablas pero estoy un poco perdido con respecto a estas consultas -->
             <div>
              <img src="img/<?php echo$row2["avatar"]?>         
              <a href="#"><?php echo $row2["usuario"]?></a>
            </div>
         <?php  } ?>
```

como veran quiero mostrar tanto los post de la tabla contenido como los post de la tabla copias juntos,  de los usuarios que son mis amigos cualquier ayuda o tips lo agradeseria mucho amigos o creen que si me sale bien con consultas separadas lo podria seguir haciendo asi sin importar el performance?

Comment: es mejor en rendimiento hacer uso de JOINS partiendo de que estas trabajando sobre un modelo relacional, por ende deben existir entidades que se vinculan unas con otras por medio de una FK; dicho lo anterior hacer consultas por separado pega en rendimiento puesto que son mas consultas a leer y ejecutar por parte del servidor

Comment: entiendo , ya me aviasn dicho es por eso que lo estoy implementando pero tengo dudas de como mostrar los resultados sastifactoriamente

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
         amigos a LEFT JOIN 
         contenido ON  contenido.id_user = a.para
         LEFT JOIN copias 
         ON contenido.id = copias.post_id  and copias.id_user = a.para
         WHERE  de='{$_SESSION["id"]}'
```

Lo tenias echo, es únicamente unir las dos consultas. y en los ON poner todas las condiciones que quieras.

Comment: muy interesante tu solucion desde que llegue a casa la probare ya que estoy en el trabajo xd , otra duda es a la hora de mostrar esa consulta como seria ya que es una consulta a dos tablas osea como saco el nombre del usuario que esta en la tabla contenido y tambien el nombre del usuario que esta en la tabla copias?  @ALBERTO PERALTA

Comment: en vez de * puedes poner los campos que quieras por ejemplo: `select contenido.usuario as usuario_contenido , copias.usuario as usuario_copias  from ...`

Comment: entiendo prove tu codigo funciono pero tuve que hacerlo asi `SELECT * FROM
         amigos a INNER JOIN 
         contenido ON  contenido.id_user = a.para
         LEFT JOIN copias 
         ON contenido.id = copias.post_id  and copias.id_user = a.para
         WHERE  de='{$_SESSION["id"]}'` por que me mostraba solo 4 publicaciones de contenido cuando en realidad hay 27 publicaciones y de copias 4 publicaciones es decir me limitaba las publicaciones de contenido a la misma cantidad que hay en conpias, pero aun asi estoy teniendo problemas pork me trata de duplicar a la misma cantidad todo

Comment: cambiando el inner join por left join en la relacion de contenido y copias se soluciona, edito la respuesta.